# discord py Setting up a log channel importing log channel id from json database

Tags: python, json, logging, discord, discord.py

So I've set up the log channel database and the event for message delete and they both work until I try and combine them so the message delete event will send the message to log channel from the database so here is some code:

```
  @commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_message_delete(self,message):
    chan = await get_logs_data()
    logchanid = chan[str(message.guild.id)]['Channel_ID']
    logchan = chan[str(message.guild.id)]['Channel_Name']
    author = message.author
    em = discord.Embed(title="Message Deleted", description=f"Owner:{author.mention}", color=RandomColor())
    em.set_thumbnail(url=author.avatar_url)
    em.add_field(name="channel:", value=message.channel.mention, inline=True)
    em.add_field(name="Channel Id:", value=message.channel.id, inline=True)
    em.add_field(name="Log channel name:", value=f"{logchan}")
    em.add_field(name="Log channel id", value=f"{logchanid}")
    em.add_field(name="Message:", value=message.content, inline=False)
    em.timestamp = message.created_at
    channel = self.client.get_channel(925930458557079646)
    await channel.send(embed=em)
```

Which when a message is deleted in discord it responds with:
[image: when channel is manually imputed]

As you can see it is reading and outputting the information from the database just fine
both log channel name and log channel id are from that database.

---

But as soon as I change

```
channel = self.client.get_channel(925930458557079646)
```

to

```
channel = self.client.get_channel(logchanid)
```

it stops working and I get the error:
[image: logchanid error]
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out just need to change it too

```
channel = self.client.get_channel(int(logchanid))
```

done